# Публичный доступ к конкретным файлам в Amazon S3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-web-services, amazon, amazon-s3

Есть ведро на **Amazon S3**

Я работаю с ним через .NET Core SDK для амазона и загружаю файлы без политики доступа (noACL), отчего они по умолчанию приватные.

Если я хочу получить ссылку на файл, чтобы можно было вставить её в HTML, я делаю так.

```
string url = _amazon.GetPreSignedUrl(pathToFile, 24(link valid time));
```

Казалось бы, идеальное решение проблемы, все защищено, а когда нужно - делается одноразовая ссылка, да только операция `GetPresignedUrl` - ужасно долгая! От 50 до 500 мс, в среднем около 300, что в случае если я гружу страничку с 100 картинками - 30 секунд загрузки только на обращение к амазону!

Поэтому вопрос - возможно ли сделать генерацию и выдачу подписанных ссылок амазоном быстрее? Может, это как то батчится, типа сразу 100 картинок затребовать, пусть выдает к ним одну ссылку например, а я распарсю, мне недолго.

Думаю, надо файлы закидывать туда с публичным доступом, но чтобы поисковой системой не индексировалось.

Ведро приватное, закидываю файл

```cs
var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    InputStream = stream,
    Key = filePath,
    BucketName = _s3BucketOptions.BucketName,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead // ЗЛОПОЛУЧНАЯ СТРОЧКА!
};
await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
```

И на строчке с явным указанием уровня доступа у мне выдает `access denied`, дескать, не могу залить файл с публичным доступом. Без этой строчки заливатся, но доступ только по долгогенерирующейся ссылке.

Как решить такую проблему? Как настроить **AWS** чтобы он не индексировался поисковиками, но конкретно по ссылке мог человек получить 1 файл, но не генерировать эту ссылку каждый раз долго.

Comment: пробовали получать ссылки параллеьно? В несколько потоков, например.

Comment: @tym32167 Это дало эффект и не плохой - время ожидания уменьшилось с 30 до 8 секунд, но всё таки это много, т.е. как общий способ решения не подойдёт.

Comment: Я обычно заливаю файл, а потом ему права выставляю, но это не програмно, а руками.